# is there a use case for the compiler to allow this? in F#

Tags: f#

I made a typo between "High" and "Height" (I blame the auto complete :)) and I ended up with a stack overflow:

```
// get the zone height
member this.Height =
    this.Height - this.Low
```

which should have read:

```
member this.Height =
    this.High - this.Low
```

Is there a legitimate case where the compiler should allow this instead of printing an error?

Comment: It's called [the halting problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Comment: No, there's not a legitimate case.  The compiler did exactly what it should have done.  Useful recursion always has a terminating condition to prevent this sort of thing from occurring.

Answer (score 2):

This is allowed because members can be referenced out of order, unlike plain F# values:

```ml
type MyType() =
    member this.A = this.B + this.B   // forward reference to member B
    member this.B = 1
```

Hence, members can be recursive without needing an explicit `rec` keyword. I think the rationale here is to conform to the way members work in other .NET languages, such as C#.

To answer your question more specifically, recursive values are unusual, but can be occasionally useful in lazy situations. For example, here's an elegant (but inefficient) [infinite sequence of Fibonacci numbers](https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence#Canonical_zipWith_implementation):

```ml
type InfiniteSeq() =
    static member Fib =
        seq {
            yield 1
            yield 1
            yield! Seq.zip InfiniteSeq.Fib (Seq.tail InfiniteSeq.Fib)
                |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> x + y)
        }

InfiniteSeq.Fib
    |> Seq.take 10
    |> Seq.toArray
    |> printfn "%A"   // [|1; 1; 2; 3; 5; 8; 13; 21; 34; 55|]
```

Note that if you try this trick with a plain value (instead of a member), you do get a scary compiler warning:

```ml
let rec fib =
    seq {
        yield 0
        yield 1
        yield! Seq.zip fib (Seq.tail fib)
            |> Seq.map (fun (x, y) -> x + y)
    }

// Warning  FS0040  This and other recursive references to the object(s) being defined will be checked for initialization-soundness at runtime through the use of a delayed reference. This is because you are defining one or more recursive objects, rather than recursive functions. This warning may be suppressed by using '#nowarn "40"' or '--nowarn:40'.
```

For another cool (but perhaps not very practical) use case, consider [Power series, power serious](https://github.com/brianberns/PowerSeries).

Comment: I have a feeling you got the question wrong, thinking it was this compile-time issue when actually it was the runtime issue mentioned in the Q and in the comments.

Comment: I beg to differ. The Q is asking why the compiler allows the code to run in the first place. The runtime behavior itself isn’t in question. The wording of the Q seems clear enough to me, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Ok, now I get your angle of attacking the question. edit: And another view on the Q.